# MATLAB quiver and usamap

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary

I am trying to use quiver to plot lat and lon data with u and v wind components with an outline map given the coordinates to the map or the latitude limits south and north and longitude limits of west and east.
I have data using quiver that looks like this:

```
lats =    
   17.4154   17.4862   17.5570   17.6278   17.6986   17.7695   17.8403   17.9113   17.9822   18.0532
   17.4406   17.5114   17.5822   17.6530   17.7239   17.7948   17.8657   17.9367   18.0077   18.0787
   17.4657   17.5365   17.6074   17.6783   17.7492   17.8201   17.8911   17.9621   18.0331   18.1042
   17.4908   17.5616   17.6325   17.7034   17.7744   17.8453   17.9163   17.9874   18.0584   18.1295
   17.5157   17.5866   17.6576   17.7285   17.7995   17.8705   17.9416   18.0126   18.0837   18.1548
   17.5407   17.6116   17.6826   17.7535   17.8246   17.8956   17.9667   18.0378   18.1089   18.1801
   17.5655   17.6365   17.7075   17.7785   17.8496   17.9207   17.9918   18.0629   18.1341   18.2053
   17.5903   17.6613   17.7324   17.8034   17.8745   17.9457   18.0168   18.0880   18.1592   18.2304
   17.6151   17.6861   17.7572   17.8283   17.8994   17.9706   18.0418   18.1130   18.1842   18.2555
   17.6398   17.7108   17.7820   17.8531   17.9242   17.9954   18.0667   18.1379   18.2092   18.2805

lons = 
 -126.6557 -126.6822 -126.7086 -126.7352 -126.7617 -126.7884 -126.8151 -126.8418 -126.8686 -126.8954
 -126.5816 -126.6079 -126.6344 -126.6608 -126.6874 -126.7139 -126.7406 -126.7672 -126.7939 -126.8207
 -126.5074 -126.5337 -126.5600 -126.5865 -126.6129 -126.6394 -126.6660 -126.6926 -126.7193 -126.7460
 -126.4331 -126.4594 -126.4857 -126.5120 -126.5384 -126.5649 -126.5914 -126.6179 -126.6445 -126.6712
 -126.3588 -126.3850 -126.4113 -126.4375 -126.4639 -126.4903 -126.5167 -126.5432 -126.5697 -126.5963
 -126.2845 -126.3106 -126.3368 -126.3630 -126.3893 -126.4156 -126.4420 -126.4684 -126.4949 -126.5214
 -126.2101 -126.2361 -126.2623 -126.2884 -126.3147 -126.3409 -126.3672 -126.3936 -126.4200 -126.4465
 -126.1356 -126.1616 -126.1877 -126.2138 -126.2400 -126.2662 -126.2924 -126.3187 -126.3451 -126.3715
 -126.0611 -126.0871 -126.1131 -126.1391 -126.1652 -126.1914 -126.2176 -126.2438 -126.2701 -126.2964
 -125.9866 -126.0125 -126.0384 -126.0644 -126.0904 -126.1165 -126.1427 -126.1688 -126.1951 -126.2214

uu = 
    4.3284    4.2194    4.1311    4.1058    4.1257    4.1565    4.1577    4.1154    4.0786    4.0919
    4.2915    4.1725    4.1192    4.0914    4.1078    4.1434    4.1444    4.1023    4.0698    4.0883
    4.2893    4.1729    4.0948    3.9822    3.9411    4.0315    4.0849    4.0789    4.0656    4.0933
    4.3015    4.1781    4.0060    3.5111    3.2246    3.6142    3.9358    4.0968    4.1293    4.1583
    4.3201    4.1979    3.9442    2.6250    2.0477    3.1333    3.9762    4.4323    4.4857    4.4572
    4.3446    4.2282    4.0007    2.9749    2.6363    3.5457    4.2251    4.5204    4.5032    4.4514
    4.3702    4.2574    4.0144    2.8532    2.4080    3.4183    4.2457    4.5984    4.5740    4.4791
    4.3983    4.2892    4.0523    2.9604    2.6090    3.6026    4.3398    4.6455    4.6028    4.4814
    4.4308    4.3219    4.0731    2.9737    2.5745    3.5884    4.3988    4.7215    4.6732    4.5380
    4.4656    4.3617    4.1061    3.0083    2.6543    3.7259    4.4764    4.7422    4.7200    4.5402

vv = 
    7.6193    7.5646    7.5514    7.5293    7.4777    7.4330    7.3959    7.3713    7.3514    7.3114
    7.5880    7.5226    7.4864    7.4412    7.3617    7.3057    7.2689    7.2468    7.2266    7.1901
    7.5464    7.5055    7.4640    7.3788    7.1708    7.0795    7.0404    7.0467    7.0437    7.0212
    7.4983    7.4718    7.4614    7.4554    6.9534    6.7995    6.7157    6.7514    6.7704    6.7739
    7.4479    7.4317    7.4620    7.8292    7.6354    7.3127    7.0606    6.9834    6.9749    6.9598
    7.3954    7.3845    7.4144    7.7126    7.6237    7.3166    7.1730    7.1403    7.0985    7.0679
    7.3465    7.3394    7.3758    7.7103    7.6388    7.3369    7.0627    6.9815    6.9544    6.9366
    7.2992    7.2950    7.3309    7.6507    7.6157    7.3175    7.1008    7.0046    6.9853    6.9644
    7.2528    7.2506    7.2908    7.6194    7.6034    7.2784    7.0555    6.9419    6.9320    6.9356
    7.2087    7.2043    7.2474    7.5870    7.5538    7.2332    7.0420    6.9274    6.9017    6.9057
```

I am trying to use quiver like this for these variables and I get a plot that looks fine:

```
quiver(lons, lats, uu, vv);
```

I am trying to overlay a map using this code using `usamap` to overlay on the quiver plot in a map outline form:

```
latlimf = [17.4154,   18.2805];
lonlimf = [-126.8954, -125.9866];
usamap(latlimf, lonlimf);
```

The problem is that the quiver plot gets **over-written** by the `usamap` request in the form of a blank map even though I am using `hold on` to keep the quiver plot.

Comment: using quiverm in the form: quiverm(lats,lons,uu,vv) gives me quiver arrows and lat and lon axis but still don't know how to use usamap or worldmap to give an outline map given the bounds of lats and lons.  thank  you

Comment: Have you tried to display the map, then do the quiver?

Comment: HI - yes, it works first with the usamap(latlim,lonlim) and then quiverm but I need the sates or region boundaries and I've tried using --- states = shaperead('usastatehi',...
    'UseGeoCoords',true,'BoundingBox',[lonlim',latlim']); with geoshow(ax,states) and I get an axis error something about expecting input number 1, LAT and matlab.graphics.axis.Axes error.

Comment: You should post all the errors and messages into your question, not into the comments.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, [`usamap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/usamap.html) always returns a new set of axes, so you have to plot that first. There is no option to make the map on an existing set of axes as you are trying to do, most likely because of the custom projection involved.

Plotting on map-projection axes requires special handling as well. Use [`quiverm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/quiverm.html) instead of the regular `quiver` to do this, and be sure to read all the caveats on the linked documentation page:

```
latlimf = [17.4154,   18.2805];
lonlimf = [-126.8954, -125.9866];
usamap(latlimf, lonlimf);
quiverm(lats, lons, vv, uu);
```

Notice that the arguments to `quiverm` are backwards compared to what you tried passing to `quiver`.